# Rails - Display all questions by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have question and category model. Question model has category_id column.

```
class Question
  belongs_to :category
end
class Category
  has_many :questions
end
```

In my controller I have this:

```
def index
   @categories = Category.all
   @questions = Question.all
end
```

I would like to display all categories and all questions that belongs_to specified category. Also, I would like to display question numbers below each category and made links of them and later it will open new page with clicked question.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
         <ul>
             <li><%= link_to question.id %></li>
         </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It should look like this but I get stuck:

> Category1
>   1     2     3     4
>
> Category2
>   1     2     3     4

Question: How to achieve that I display questions like is show above?

Comment: Make it like this, it will improve your query -> `@categories = Category.includes(:questions)`, also dnt touch `ids` of table, just add extra column named `position`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

Controller:

```
def index
   @categories = Category.all
end
```

View:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
    <% category.questions.each do |question| %>
         <ul>
             <li><%= link_to question.id, question_path %></li>
         </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks..that was good answer. Another question is it possible when displaying question id's to make them start always from one? Id's are different (i.e. 8, 12, 24) but I need 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6?

Comment: @Unknown19 It's completely another question, maybe you should create another one for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you want to display all of the categories, and the questions that belong to each of those categories, I'm assuming that the index action that you pasted in comes from your categories_controller.

One solution I can think of would be to change the instance variables inside your index. I don't really see a purpose for having the instance variable that references all of your Question objects. This is the one I'm talking about:

```
@questions = Question.all
```

Yea, get rid of that. You should be fine with just

```
@categories = Category.all
```

Since you want to display all of your categories, that instance variable is necessary. And since you mentioned you want to also display all of the questions that belong to each category, that instance variable is sufficient with the right view. You were on the right track, but instead, just use the @categories instance variable; forget about @questions. Here is what your view should probably look like (you were on the right track above):

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
      <% category.questions.each do |question| %>
      <ul>
         <li><%= link_to question.id, question_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also note that in that first line of code, when you start a block, you don't need the <%= , You only need the <%. That's because that first line of the block is purely ruby in itself, it isn't actually getting printed to the resulting html. 
Hope I helped a little bit!

*** Also: I saw another answer on here which is missing something: When you use the <%= link_to %> helper, you need to specify the first argument which is the resulting markup (In this case you wanted the question.id) , AND ALSO A SECOND ARGUMENT, which is the path for the link to follow ***

Comment: Thanks..that was good answer also, but Maxim answered little before you. Another question is it possible when displaying question id's to make them start always from one? Id's are different (i.e. 8, 12, 24) but I need 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6?

Comment: @Unknown19 Not that I know of... Maybe wait a little longer and see if someone else comments with a solution. I think you may have to write your own helper method or something with a little. That might be some fun practice.